How to debug self develop toolbox in Scilab/XCOS?
I have one tool box and there is error "Problem in port size or type."  How to debug it? Do we have something like MATLAB?
Its university project.
Problem is with below two file
function block = Kalman_Filter_SIM(block, flag)
    exec("macros/Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci", -1);  // Load utility functions

    // Debugging: Display sizes of inputs and outputs
    disp("Input sizes:")
    disp(size(block.inptr))
    disp("Output sizes:")
    disp(size(block.outptr))

    // Check the number of inputs
    if size(block.inptr, 1) ~= 2 then
        error("Kalman_Filter_SIM: Expected 2 inputs for state prediction, received: " + string(size(block.inptr, 1)));
    end

    // Process noise and measurement noise covariance
    Q = diag([0.01, 0.01]);
    R = 0.1;

    select flag
    case -5 
        disp("Kalman_Filter_SIM: Error (-5)");

    case 0  // State Prediction
        [x_kf, P_kf] = reverseAndReshape(block.x, 2);
        
        f = [x_kf(2); -block.inptr(2)];  // Use noise input for f
        A = [0 1; -1 0];
        dx_kf = f;
        dP_kf = A * P_kf * A' + Q;
        block.xd = concatAB(dx_kf, dP_kf);

    case 1  // Output Update
        [x_kf, P_kf] = reverseAndReshape(block.x, 2);
        block.outptr(1) = x_kf;

    case 2  // Measurement Update
        [x_kf, P_kf] = reverseAndReshape(block.x, 2);
        
        // Check input size for measurement
        if size(block.inptr, 1) ~= 1 then
            error("Kalman_Filter_SIM: Expected 1 input for measurement update, received: " + string(size(block.inptr, 1)));
        end

        C = [1 0];
        K = P_kf * C' / (C * P_kf * C' + R);
        z = block.inptr(1);
        x_kf = x_kf + K * (z - C * x_kf);
        P_kf = (eye(size(K, 1)) - K * C) * P_kf;
        block.x = concatAB(x_kf, P_kf);

    case 4  // Initialization
        initial_state = [0.0; 0.0];
        initial_covariance = [1.0, 0.0; 0.0, 1.0];
        block.x = [initial_state; initial_covariance(:)];

    case 5
        disp("Kalman_Filter_SIM: Ending (5)");
    end
endfunction


function [x, y, typ] = Kalman_Filter_IF(job, arg1, arg2)
    x = [];
    y = [];
    typ = [];
    
    exec("macros/Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci", -1);  // Load utility functions

    initial_state = [0; 0];  // Initial state vector
    initial_covariance = [1.0, 0.0; 0.0, 1.0];  // Initial covariance matrix

    select job
    case "plot" then
        standard_draw(arg1);
        
    case "getinputs" then
        [x, y, typ] = standard_inputs(arg1);
        
    case "getoutputs" then
        [x, y, typ] = standard_outputs(arg1);
        
    case "getorigin" then
        [x, y] = standard_origin(arg1);

    case "set" then
        x = arg1;  // Essential for handling properties
        graphics = arg1.graphics;
        exprs = graphics.exprs;
        model = arg1.model;

        title = "Set Parameters";
        labels = ['Initial state [position, velocity]'; 'Covariance matrix for position and velocity'];
        types = list('vec', 2, 'mat', [2, 2]);
        
        [ok, State, Covariance, exprs] = getvalue(title, labels, types, exprs); 

        if ok then
            [model.rpar, isError] = EncodeRparIpar_KF(model.rpar, State, Covariance);
            graphics.exprs = exprs;
            x.graphics = graphics;
            x.model = model;
        else
            warning('Kalman_Filter_IF: Set: Cancelled!');
        end

    case "define" then
        model = scicos_model();
        model.sim = list("Kalman_Filter_SIM", 5);  // Link to the simulation function
        
        // Inputs: One for measurement and one for noise
        model.in = [1; 2];  
        model.intyp = [1; 1];  // Both inputs are real matrices
        
        // Output: State
        model.out = [1];  
        model.outtyp = [1];  // Output is a real matrix
        
        model.state = [initial_state; initial_covariance(:)];
        model.blocktype = "c";
        model.dep_ut = [%t, %t];  // True for both input and output
        
        exprs = ["[0.0; 0.0]"; "1.0, 0.0; 0.0, 1.0"];
        x = standard_define([4 4], model, exprs);
        x.graphics.style = ['blockWithLabel;displayedLabel=Kalman_Filter'];
        
        // Ensure the block is large enough to show two inputs and one output
        x.graphics.z = [0; 0; 1; 1];  // Adjust z parameter to handle multiple inputs and outputs
        x.graphics.inport = [1; 2];  // Set the input port properties
        x.graphics.outport = [1];     // Set the output port property
        
        // Debugging: Display port information
        disp("Input ports: " + string(model.in));
        disp("Output ports: " + string(model.out));
        disp("Input types: " + string(model.intyp));
        disp("Output types: " + string(model.outtyp));
    end
endfunction


I try debug method and display method. I want my kalman filter should work like demo kalman filter mention in the Scilab demo file.
